# How can I get access to the folder

Tags: permissions, root

i recently install Ubuntu 15.10 after windows 10   now my problem is that i do not have permission to delete or move any file or folder. please help me with this

Comment: Please explain your problem verbosely.

Comment: Which folder? You have access to all things in `/home/USERNAME`.

Comment: i install ubuntu recently after windows 10 now i can read the data of windows 10 , every file, folder what i have stored  in windows 10. but i cannot delete, moves that data. hope u understand now my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if Windows mount was done with another uid/gid. Please check your `/etc/fstab` according to the [ArchWiki instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G).

Basically, your mount line should looks like that:

```
UUID=01CD2ABB65E17DE0 /media/Windows ntfs-3g uid=user,gid=users,dmask=022,fmask=133 0 0
```

where `user` is your `$USER` and `users` is your group (probably `$USER` also).